# Does it make sense to make every function in an ERC20 Token Contract unpayable?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

Does it make sense to make every function in an ERC20 Token Contract unpayable using

```
require(msg.value == 0);
```

just in case that someone accidentally sends eth to the contract.

Answer (score 2):

No. A function requires the `payable` modifier to receive ETH.

There's also a fallback (no name) function that can be made `payable` or not. But it must be made payable.

Keep in mind inheritance if you're using libraries/frameworks.